# nxlog & logstash - dropping messages that dont match a given EventID

Tags: logstash, nxlog

I am using Nxlog to forward my Windows Server logs to LogStash and trying to remove messages from LogStash that are not equal to a given windows eventId. What is the correct syntax for this?

Here is what i have tried:

```
if [type] == "WindowsLog" {
            if      [EventID] <> 123
                    {

                            drop { }
            }
```

and:

```
 if [type] == "WindowsLog" {
            if      ![EventID] == 123
                    {

                            drop { }
            }
```

and

```
if [type] == "WindowsLog" {
            if      [EventID] != 123
                    {

                            drop { }
            }
```

Comment: The last one should be fine (except that it's missing a closing brace at the end, but I assume that's a copy/paste mistake), but it probably requires that your EventID field is an integer field (and not a string field). Is it?

Comment: Thank you, i added it to its own if statement as it had other statements below there where i was trying to add tags. I now have it working but only for a single EventID. When trying to add an or statement it seems to drop all events. `    if [type] == "WindowsLog" {
                if      [EventID] != 538  or [EventID] != 540 {
                                drop { }
                                }


                }

Comment: Yes, because no matter what event id you have, it's either not equal to 538 _or_ it's not equal to 540. You want to drop messages whose event id is not equal to 538 _and_ not equal to 540.

Comment: In this instance, 538 and 540 are both the events i want to keep (im using these 2 to test as they are common in my logs). Using the AND operator, i only get the 538 messages and not the 540?

Comment: Then I don't know what's up. Logically it's the correct condition; if the event id isn't 538 and isn't 540, drop the message.

Answer (score 0):

[EventID] == 123
this should match and then you can drop.